# Installing R Language on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I've checked all the resources and tutorials from the internet and it seems all are requiring to install **Anaconda** just to build the **R kernel**.

Is there a way to add **R kernel** to my jupyter notebook without installing **Anaconda**? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my problem, by installing **R** into my machine. Upon installing, run the application and I follow this [tutorial](https://irkernel.github.io/installation/), by just copying the stated command.

Here's the [link](https://courses.edx.org/courses/UTAustinX/UT.7.01x/3T2014/56c5437b88fa43cf828bff5371c6a924/) for the installation of native R.